# Primefaces InputText stores previous value when present inside the Primefaces Dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I have a InputText inside a Dialog as:

```
<p:dialog header="Demo Header"appendTo="@(body)"
            widgetVar="sectionDialog" id="section_Dialog"
            modal="true">
            
            <h:panelGroup id="myPanel">

                <h:panelGrid columns="4">

                    <h:outputLabel value="Count: "/>

                    <pe:keyFilter mask="num" for="count" />
                    <p:inputText id="count"
                        value="#{myBean.countValue}" converter="spaceConverter">
                    </p:inputText>

                    <p:commandButton id="btnId" process="@this"
                        update="secondPanel" value="ADD" icon="ui-icon-check"
                        action="#{myBean.generateDataTableBasedOnCount()}" ajax="true"
                        partialSubmit="true">
                    </p:commandButton>

                </h:panelGrid>

            </h:panelGroup>


            <h:panelGroup style="border:0" id="secondPanel">
                    ...// data table generated based on Input Count.
            </h:panelGroup> 

</p:dialog>
```

If I keep the InputText and Button outside the dialog, it works like a charm.
**But when I keep them inside the Dialog, *myBean.countValue* always stores the previous input value.**
When I refresh the page and enter a new value, Old Value is being stored in the bean.

What am I missing here?

---

PrimeFaces           : 5.3

PrimeFaces-Extension : 4.0.0

JSF                  : 2.2.8

---

Answer (score 1):

You need to ResetInput of the dialog before you open it.

See: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/resetInput.xhtml

So on the button that opens your dialog... Its better to reset the FORM but I didn't see the h:form in your example code above.

```xml
 <p:commandButton value="Open Dialog" update="section_Dialog">
        <p:resetInput target="section_Dialog"/>
</p:commandButton
```